# Get row index in repetitive values in Data Frame

Tags: r, indexing, data.table, row

I have a large Dataset (50 000 rows) with data similar to this:

```
CODE        sYS     YEAR  MONTH VAR STATION
00000539    BREAK   1998    12   n  HUAYAN
00000539    BREAK   2003    12   n  HUAYAN
00000539    BREAK   2008    12   n  HUAYAN
00000539    BREAK   2009    12   n  HUAYAN
00000539    BREAK   2015    12   n  HUAYAN
00000543    BREAK   1992    12   n  NANA
00000543    BREAK   2008    12   n  NANA
00000543    BREAK   2010    12   n  NANA
00000638    BREAK   1971    12   n  PACARAN
00000638    BREAK   1973    12   n  PACARAN
00000638    BREAK   1997    12   n  PACARAN
00000727    BREAK   1973    12   n  COPARA
00000727    BREAK   1995    12   n  COPARA
00000727    BREAK   1997    12   n  COPARA
00000727    BREAK   1998    12   n  COPARA
```

What i want is to get the row index of specific years like e.g.

```
x <- c(1973, 1998, 2008)
```

I tried this:

```
> row_index <- match(x, DataSet$Year)
> print(row_index)
> 10 1 3
```

As can you see with "match()" i only get the first value and not all, because what i expected i like this:

```
> 10 12 1 15 3 7
```

Any advice or help. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe library(data.table); setDT(Dataset)[YEAR %in% x, which=TRUE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `which` -

```
row_index <- which(DataSet$Year %in% x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> with(DataSet, YEAR[duplicated(YEAR) & duplicated(STATION)])
[1] 2008 1997 1998
```